# jQuery UI autocomplete source merged for different form element

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form with multiple text input and trying to get each one to autocomplete from different sources using jQuery UI. The problem is the sources are merged together. Please have a look at my code and let me know what I have done wrong.

The form HTML:

```
<label>State: </label>
<input class='ac_state' name='state' type='text' />

<label>District: </label>
<input class='ac_district' name='district' type='text />

<label>Town: </label>
<input class='ac_town' name='town' type='text' />
```

The javascript for each input, all in one page, looks like this (I only include two here):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    var availableTagsDistrict = <?php include('../inc/autocomplete_district.php'); ?>;
    $('.ac_district').autocomplete({
      source: availableTagsDistrict,
    });
  });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    var availableTagsTown = <?php include('../inc/autocomplete_town.php'); ?>;
    $('.ac_town').autocomplete({
      source: availableTagsTown,
    });
  });
</script>
```

The result from mysql is returned in json_encode format. One such example for district:

```
require('../../inc/connect.php');

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT district FROM source";

$results = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);

if ($results->num_rows) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

    $result[] = trim($row['district']);

    }
}

mysqli_close($cxn);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, turns out my query keep on adding to the $result[] array which is then posted into the availableTags in the all the javascript. Such a noob.